# Websocket transport doesn't work on my Firefox/Chrome (Windows version)

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I'm using the latest stable version of Firefox/Chrome on Windows to test my application (use socket.io). But the websocket transport doesn't work, in browser console it sent message that shows it supports Websocket, xhr-polling... but it doesn't work then fallback to use others (about 10s later).

I bring the source code to run on Ubuntu (in a VM) and test with Firefox/Chrome on Ubuntu, it works well with websocket instantly. Then I try to use Windows version of 2 browsers to test with server on Ubuntu, websocket doesn't work (the same as server on Windows) then fallback. So I think the problems are my Windows or Firefox/Chrome on it.

I don't know why: Does it happen to others computer using Windows or there is something wrong with Windows Firewall?

Update: Websocket works in Safari on Windows. I try to uninstall Firefox and Chrome, it still doesn't work. I tried and it works on other Windows 7 computer (my friends and on VM). There must be some problems with my Windows 7.

Comment: Is there is any proxy settings in browsers, they might to mess up connectivity.

Comment: I don't use any proxy settings. http://www.websocket.org/echo.html, when I test with this Firefox and Chrome work with TLS. I try to disable all firewall and anti-virus, but it still don't work.

Comment: Is it local area network? What IP you are trying to connect to using WebSockets? Where html files are hosted? Maybe you have problem with visibility over the network..

Comment: At first, I try to use socket.io. It works well with Safari on Windows but not Firefox/Chrome (which also works on Ubuntu and other Windows). It seems to have problems on my Windows, poor me. I think I should try to re-install Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your antivirus isn't blocking WebSockets: https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Socket.IO-and-firewall-software

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same problem. The way out of this is to make your web-sockets secure. Switch to wss calls and everything should be fine.